# I can't get result of google lighthouse in java

Tags: java, process, lighthouse

everybody.

I'm trying to launch google lighthouse and get result as .json file in java application.
I launched google lighthouse but it doesn't generate .json file.
Here is my java code.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", "lighthouse https://www.google.com --output json --output-path report.json --disable-device-emulation --throttling-method=provided");
Process process = builder.start();
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
assert exitCode == 0;
```

How can i fix it?
Thanks in advance.